# Does the kernel have a main() function?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers

I am learning device drivers and Kernel programming. According to Jonathan Corbet's book, there is no `main()` function in device drivers.

So I two questions:

- Why don't we need a `main()` function in device drivers?
- Does the kernel itself have a `main()` function?

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Also asked by the same user here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18266063/827263

Comment: @KeithThompson... Yes... Just because I did not get answer what I want so I asked it here.

Comment: @Shadur... anyway now it is about to closed...And I do not have privileged to migrate that...

Comment: This should have been closed the other way around, this one has much more views :-)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

In user space programs, `main()` is the entry point to the program that is [called by the libc initialization code](https://web.archive.org/web/20140127034812/http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html) when the binary is executed. Kernel code does not have the luxury to rely on libc, as libc itself relies on the kernel syscall interface for memory allocation, I/O, process managements etc.

That said, the equivalent of `main()` in kernel code is `start_kernel()`, which is [called by the bootloader](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linuxboot/index.html) after having loaded the kernel image, decompressed it into memory and setup essential hardware and memory paging. `start_kernel()` performs the majority of the system setup and eventually spawns the init process.

The entry point to Linux kernel modules is an init function that is registered with the kernel by calling the `module_init()` macro. The registered module init function is then [called by kernel code](http://linuxgazette.net/157/amurray.html) through the `do_initcalls()` function during kernel startup.

Comment: Thank you for recognizing the real purpose of the `main` method in C. (It is an all too commonly held misconception that the OS makes a direct call to `main`, which isn't the case and is even less the case in e.g. C++.) I'd give you another upvote if I could just for that.

Comment: @Thomas... Thanks for this excellent answer....

Answer (score 18):

The kernel does not have a `main` function.  `main` is a concept of the C language. The kernel is written in C and assembly. The entry code  of the kernel is written by assembly.

The boot sequence is organized as follows:

1. The BIOS usually loads a boot loader from a boot block device. A popular boot loader right now is grub.
2. Grub loads a kernel image into ram, possible with an initial root device (`initrd`). Then code at some address is executed.
3. The kernel image has some kernel modules, for example: filesystem modules, device drivers. The kernel image use the filesystem module to mount the root filesystem. Now the kernel can load and run all kernel modules from disk.
4. The kernel runs initialization tasks. For example: traverse PCI bus and find all PCI devices, initialize all device drivers.
5. Finally the kernel creates process 0 and process 1 (the `init` process), switches the context of CPU from ring 0 to ring 3, and starts the init process (the process id is 1). Now the kernel boot is finished!
6. The `init` program runs all init scripts. All services are started. Shell is  called. Users can login.

The `main` function is a C function. Actually main method is not the entry point of C programs. The C runtime calls many functions before `main`.
GCC has a extend feature: constructors. Functions declared "constructor" are called before `main`.

For example:

```
/* This should not be used directly. Use block_init etc. instead. */ 
#define module_init(function, type) \
    static void _attribute__((constructor)) do_qemu_init ## function(void) { \
    register_module_init(function, type); \
}
```

This macro is from the qemu project.

Comment: Main method is a c method.Actually main method is not the entry of c program.C runtime has called many methods before main method.

Comment: well, bios usually loads a boot loader, and that boot loader loads a kernel image (and possibly an initrd). The code of the kernel is in the kernel image, not initrd

Comment: GCC has a extend feature:  constructor.  The method declaration "constructor" is called before main method.   For example: 
/* This should not be used directly.  Use block_init etc. instead.  */
#define module_init(function, type)                                         \
static void __attribute__((constructor)) do_qemu_init_ ## function(void) {  \
    register_module_init(function, type);                                   \
}

Comment: Well,1)bios usually load a boot loader----most popular is "grub".  2) Grub load a kernel image(most popular is initrd.img)   3) kernel image has some kernel module,for example:filesystem module,device driver. kernel image use filesystem module to mount  root filesystem. Now kernel can run all kernel code.  4)kernel exec init work. Finally kernel create process 0 and process 1.Switch the context of CPU from ring 0 to ring 3,and init process(The process id is 1) exec code.Now kernel booted has finished!

Comment: Please edit your answer if you need to add more information.

Comment: `initrd.img` *IS NOT* the kernel image.  It's a set of modules loaded by the kernel at boot.  Kernel images usually have names starting with "vmlinuz" but differ from distro to distro.

Comment: This answer is chock-full of "everything is a PC/Linux/i86" and it boots that way and the kernel is that way... Why does everybody think that's the only possible way in the world?

Answer (score 10):

There is e.g. a main() function in [arch/x86/boot/main.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/boot/main.c) for preparing the system to switch from the real to the protected mode but other architectures don't have such a code. There is a nice [overview](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/kernel-boot-process) how booting of Linux kernel 2.6.x on x86 platform works. It's really worth reading it.

According the document [HOWTO do Linux kernel development](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/HOWTO), the Linux kernel is

> a freestanding C environment, with no reliance on the standard C library, so some portions of the C standard are not supported.

what according the C standard BTW means that

> It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a 'main' function.